# Case-insensitive filter in Django admin using SimpleListFilter

Tags: django, filter, admin

I have a SimpleListFilter in the Django admin panel that filters values (ingredients) based on their first letters (see the code below). The issue is that ingredients could be saved/updated in the database with either uppercase or lowercase letters. Because of this, the filter starts behaving incorrectly, displaying two fields for the same letter (for example, A(1) and a(70)).

[image]

I've addressed the problem by overwriting CharField in my models (see the code below). But I'm not satisfied with this solution as it's not universal. Is there a way to make this filter case-insensitive without modifying the values before adding them into the database? I want the filter to work regardless of the letter case. (for example, A(71)).

```
class FirstLetterAlphabetiseFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('First letter')
    parameter_name = 'first_letter'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        ingredients = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        for letter in sorted(
            ''.join(set(ingredient.name[0] for ingredient in ingredients))
        ):
            count = ingredients.filter(name__istartswith=letter).count()
            if count:
                yield (letter, f'{letter} ({count})')

    def queryset(self, request, ingredients):
        if not self.value():
            return ingredients
        return ingredients.filter(
            name__istartswith=(self.value()))
```

```
class NameField(models.CharField):
    """Converts NameField into lower case while saving in database."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NameField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).lower()
```

UPD

```
@register(Ingredient) class IngredientAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'measurement_unit')
    search_fields = ('name', 'measurement_unit',)
    list_filter = (FirstLetterAlphabetiseFilter, MeasurementUnitFilter,)
```

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    """Ingredient model. M2M connection with Recipe model."""

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=settings.INGREDIENT_CHARFIELD_MAX_LEN,
        verbose_name=_('Name')
    )
    measurement_unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=settings.INGREDIENT_CHARFIELD_MAX_LEN,
        verbose_name=_('Measurement unit')
    )
```

Comment: What is the collation of the database?

Comment: Can you also share the `ModelAdmin` itself?

Comment: It's a case-sensitive collation. 
I've updated the post with the ModelAdmin and Ingredient model. Please have a look.

Comment: When constructing the choices for your filter why not convert the first letter of each name to uppercase so you only create uppercase choices?

Comment: I've tried, but in the def queryset() the ingredients are filtered by the first letter, and they are stored in the database with both uppercase and lowercase letters. So if I get 'alphabet' from upper letters in def lookups(), further , def queryset() only gives me the ingredients that are written with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I think your filter would work as is if you just add `.upper()` in the lookups method here `set(ingredient.name[0].upper() for ingredient in ingredients)`

Comment: Thanks, but that would not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I came up with:

```
class FirstLetterAlphabetiseFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('First letter')
    parameter_name = 'first_letter'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        ingredients = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        for letter in sorted(
            ''.join(set(ingredient.name[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients))
        ):
            count = (
                    ingredients.filter(name__istartswith=letter).count()
                    + ingredients.filter(name__istartswith=letter.upper()).count()
            )
            if count:
                yield (letter, f'{letter} ({count})')

    def queryset(self, request, ingredients):
        if not self.value():
            return ingredients
        return ingredients.filter(
            Q(name__istartswith=self.value().upper()) | Q(name__istartswith=self.value())
        )
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me improve it or suggest a better solution.